# Exporting Specific DataGridView Hidden/visible Columns to TXT (not entire DataGridView)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, dataset, export-to-text

My post is in relation to a Visual Basic Windows Forms Program. I've got a datagridview (called: Device_LabelsDataGridView) which has a mix of visible and invisible columns placed in a Dialog.

I am wanting to export a specific two columns titled 'Location" (which is hidden) and "Data" (which is visible) but miss out the middle column called "Description". At the minute, the code provided further down exports my data like this (with the commas just like they are):

```
Location,Description,Data
Location,Description,Data
Location,Description,Data
Continued…
```

But I am wanting (again, with the commas just as they are)

```
Location,Data
Location,Data
Location,Data
Continued…
```

Below is the code I have tried to use, but can't get what I want.

```
Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\GridExport.txt")
    If (DeviceLabels.Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DeviceLabels.Device_LabelsDataGridView.Columns
        Next
    End If

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DeviceLabels.Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows
        'If Not omitIndices.Contains(row.Index) Then
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If (cell.OwningColumn.Index = (DeviceLabels.Device_LabelsDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1)) Then
                If (Not (cell.Value) Is Nothing) Then
                    writer.WriteLine(cell.Value.ToString)
                Else
                    writer.WriteLine("")
                End If

            ElseIf (Not (cell.Value) Is Nothing) Then
                writer.Write(String.Concat(cell.Value.ToString, ","))
            Else
                writer.Write(String.Concat("", ","))
            End If
        Next
        'End If
    Next

    writer.Close()

End Sub
```

Can someone help? I don't have much hair left! I am a newcomer to VB and have 0 experience, nor can I find any relevant examples that incorporate exporting visible and invisible columns.

I need text files too, so no other format can be used. The program I am creating is an EEPROM programmer. Once this text export works I can work on the next half of my program- sending the files to my EEPROM handler.

Answer (score 0):

I find using the old X,Y to access the DGV is easy to code if you are just looking for values:

Here's my test case:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sLine As String = ""
    Dim sLines As String = "" ' added
    For iRow As Integer = 0 To Device_LabelsDataGridView.RowCount - 1
        sLine = ""
        For iCol As Integer = 0 To Device_LabelsDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
            ' test header text: Device_LabelsDataGridView.Columns(iCol).HeaderText
            If iCol = 0 Or iCol = 1 Then
                sLine &= Device_LabelsDataGridView(iCol, iRow).Value.ToString & "," 
            End If
        Next
        sLines &= sLine.Substring(0, sLine.Length - 1) & vbCrLf
    Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Test.txt", sLines, True) ' generated from right click, snippets
End Sub
Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows.Add({"1a", "1b", "1c"})
    Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows.Add({"2a", "2b", "2c"})
    Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows.Add({"3a", "", ""})
    Device_LabelsDataGridView.Rows.Add({"4a", "4b", "4c"})
End Sub
```

I added three columns to the DGV and made the 2nd Visible=False and turned off the option to be able to add rows (click the little > in the upper right of the DGV.)

It doesn't make any difference if the column is visible or not.

I just test the column index to see if I should include the column or not. You could test the HeaderText for a column or other property.

The .Cell.Value.Tostring deals with empty cells OK.

Comment: Like I say I am a beginner.. I have no idea if your code even publishes a text file, or where it would save it. So is this editing my datagridview with new columns?

Comment: Sorry - I just provided an outline of part of the solution. Pretty difficult too post a complete application.... I edited the above to accumulate the lines and then right them to a file.

Comment: You can ignore my DataGridView loading and use your DataGridView. Remove the DeviceLabels prefix on your references to your grid. modify the test for which columns to include in the output.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much!!! Small issue, any new export is being appended to the same file, is it possible to overwrite the file once I press the button?

Comment: Press F1 just behind the method/property you need help with - in this case WriteAllText. And/or place your cursor inside the parameter list, type a space, and you should see the description of the parameters. In the above example the third parameter is True which indicates the data will be appended if the file exists. Also, at the bottom of the help for WriteAllText is a link to a broad topic on working with files in VB.Net.